# Embed youtube video without any logo or link to youtube

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube, blogs

I need to embed a Youtube video without Youtube Logo and any Link to Youtube video site.

There are three options:
- modestbranding = 1 To remove the youtube logo
- controls = 0 To remove the botton bar with link to "see in youtube"
- showinfo 0 0 To remove the upper bar with link to "see in youtube"

If I put one or two of them, works but still users can go to youtube using the third option.

If I join three options, automatically Youtube logo appears.

I use something like this:

src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoID??modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&controls=0"

How can I fix it or how can I embed a video without any posibility to find it in youtube.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Don't use YouTube? I don't think most video hosting services are going to give you a way to hide the fact that the video is on their site/using their service unless you pay to be able to hide that.

Comment: I agree with @BSMP. It is not cheap for companies to stream video and I expect all will at the least want to brand themselves. You can use the HTML5 '<video>' tag and host the video yourself as a .webm and .mp4 format, that is one alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly, `showinfo` and `modestbranding` are mutually exclusive.

#### `modestbranding` - [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

> This parameter lets you use a YouTube player that does not show a YouTube logo. Set the parameter value to 1 to prevent the YouTube logo from displaying in the control bar. Note that a small YouTube text label will still display in the upper-right corner of a paused video when the user's mouse pointer hovers over the player.

#### And `showinfo` - [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

> **Supported values are 0 and 1.**
>
> Setting the parameter's value to 0 causes the player to not display
> information like the video title and uploader before the video starts
> playing.

Answer (score 0):

[working demo](https://shareallweb.com/youtube/youcool66.php)with sandbox

```html
 <div style="border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); overflow: hidden; height: 800px  margin: 50px auto; max-width: 600px;">
<iframe scrolling="yes" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/snTlMy80c_E?autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1&rel=0;modestbranding=1&showsearch=0" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: 0px; height: 500px; margin-top: -60px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Without sandbox. No title or header links plus youtube logo is hidden. Without sandbox the links like related videos are clickable. [working demo here](https://shareallweb.com/youtube/youcool6.php)

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); overflow: hidden; height: 800px  margin: 50px auto; max-width: 600px;">
<iframe scrolling="yes" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/snTlMy80c_E?autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1&rel=0;modestbranding=1&showsearch=0" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: 0px; height: 500px; margin-top: -60px; width: 100%;"    sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation" ></div>
```